# Trusted Web Activity & Bubblewrap forcing the render engine (Chromium/firefox/geko)

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity, android-customtabs, bubblewrap

Is there a way with bubblewrap when building a TWA to force the #custom-tabs engine that is used? Ie at the moment if a user has their default browser set as Firefox the TWA installed will use the Firefox/gecko implementation...

I'd rather force TWA to use chromium #custom-tabs due to additional APIs available and CSS handling..
Additionally testing is far easier with one engine than two.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bubblewrap doesn't provide an option to always use a specific provider. That is by design, for two reasons:

- it's not possible to guarantee that a given browser will be installed for all users.
- favour the user's browser choice.

It is possible to modify the app directly to get this behaviour, but due to the reasons above, not recommended.